# Visual Studio 2022 doesn't show Projects on Solution and Indexing Files forever

Tags: visual-studio

anyone knows how to solve this?

Happens with previous versions of Visual Studio, such as 2019 and 2017.
Visual Studio doesn't show Projects on Solution and Indexing Files forever. Can't even run the program file.

[image]

Already tryed everything, fully uninstall Visual Studio related programs, .SDKs and Runtimes.

Comment: Definitely not happening to me.  I am using VS 2022.  I see you are on Windows 11, I wonder if that has anything to do with it.  I've only used Visual Studio on Windows 10 machines

Comment: it used to work in win10 :/

Comment: I'm having this problem now. Ugh. It's sooooo frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I did noticed the same thing, installed SDK, indexing kept going.  When I check my sdks on terminal (`dotnet --list-sdks`), I saw nothing.  Finally, I ended up removing `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` from my PATH, leaving only `C:\Program Files\dotnet` and when I check the sdks on terminal, they were there.  Opened visual studio and it loaded the Avalonia projects with no issues.  Anyways, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, solved the issue with vs2022